# Is it possible to click on map marker icon on a map, in which all map marker icon is having same <div> structure

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to click the specific one map marker icon, which is highlighted inside the image. Inside image all map marker is showing with same  tag. so i am not able to clicking the map marker icon.

Like my scenario is after clicking the map marker icon, one pop up is showing with the listing name. suppose my listing name is "xyz" so, i want to verify that the listing name "xyz" is present on the map or not?

so, my first step will be find the map marker icon which listing name is having "xyz".

HTML Code Snippet.

```html
<div id="map_canvas" class="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);">
<div class="gm-style" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; -moz-user-select: none; z-index: 0;">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; -moz-user-select: none; z-index: 0; cursor: pointer;" title="Formosa Centre">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 100%;">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 2; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; -moz-user-select: none;"/>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 3; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; -moz-user-select: none;"/>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 4; width: 100%;">
<div style="width: 1px; height: 1px; z-index: 1000; position: absolute; left: 436px; top: 450px;"/>
```

Refer Image.

[image]

I have tried this code, but it is not working for me. i have used xpath along with div tag with using style attribute.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 3; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; -moz-user-select: none;']"))));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 3; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; -moz-user-select: none;']")).click();
String title = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h6/a/span[contains(text(), 'SN Estates')]")).getText();
System.out.println(title);
```

Comment: Can you share page `URL`?

Comment: Hello, @Andersson Site Url is http://demo.templatic.com/directory/

Comment: Do you need to check exact item or it doesn't matter? I can click on icon marker, but it seem to be just a marker in center of map  ("The little escape"). To click on any other marker you should get its exact coordinates which could be quite difficult

Comment: I need to click on specific one map marker icon, which name is having "SN Estates"

Comment: Do you need to just check that detailed info pop-up for `SN Estates` can be opened or you need exactly to click marker to check it. You can check this pop-up in a different way without clicking

Comment: yes, @Anderson i want to check detailed info pop-up for `SN Estates`, if you will provide me your solution. then i will be so grateful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to click marker icon to see detailed info about target place- you can use search field in left bottom corner of page to complete the same:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("search_string"))).sendKeys("SN Estates");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("ptitle")));
String title = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ptitle']/span")).getText();
System.out.println(title);
```

Comment: Hi, @Anderson That's the exact solution that i'm looking for. Thanks it working very well.